# Using C# to load documents in default browser using a dataURI

Tags: c#

I have a C# desktop application that receives document data from a web service.

I tried loading the documents using:

```
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(browserName, "data:application/pdf;base64, " + base64EncodedPDF));
```

however, this fails when the command line parameter exceeds the maximum allowable size.

Is there a workaround for this, one that doesn't require writing a file to the local system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [microsoft docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation), the character limit is 8191 characters for starting a process.

Options I can think of in order of most practical to least:

- Writing it to a temp file (definitely the most straightforward option but you noted you wanted to avoid this)
- Upload to cloud file storage like azure blob storage or AWS S3 and open that link
- Using Kestrel or HttpListener to host the data from a local URL temporarily and open that
- Using something like Selenium or PuppeteerSharp to remote control the browser and navigate to the data URL after opening the browser